# Whats the explanation for this behaviour?

Tags: python, printing, pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path(r"C:\Users\SerT\Desktop\a.txt")
print (file.name)

file.rename(file.with_name("b.txt"))
print (file.name)
```

i'd like to know why file.name prints out "a.txt" in both instances even though the file actually gets renamed in windows explorer

Comment: `with_name` and `rename` ***return a new `Path`***, they don't modify the existing `file` object.

Answer (score 0):

`.rename` doesn't modify the file object, instead it simply returns the new filepath. If you want to rename a file, you can set file equal to the `file.rename` method:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

file = Path(r"C:\Users\SerT\Desktop\a.txt")
print (file.name)

file = file.rename(file.with_name("b.txt"))
print(file.name)
```

Comment: `Path.rename()` _does_ rename the target. So `os.rename()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The file is being renamed, but the original `Path` object (`file` in your case) is not changed itself.

Since [`Path.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) returns a new Path object, to get the result you're expecting, do:

```py
file = file.rename(file.with_name("b.txt"))
print(file.name)
```